# Multiple div in same line bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want multiple div in same line with overflow option.

```css
.col-xs-3 a{height:100px;background:pink;display:block;margin-top:10px;padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content1</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content2</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content3</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content4</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content5</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content6</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap` along with making the elements to be `inline`. Add some width to make the overflow confined to the current element:

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.col-xs-3 a {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content1</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content2</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content3</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content4</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content5</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><a>content6</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any option without `white-space` ?

Comment: @user12345 This is the right way boss. I don't think you can force anything in one single line without using it. Why not `white-space`? I am ready to give a better answer, if you can put more context on what you are looking at?

Comment: @user12345 I just checked for you. No other way mate... Only this way!

Comment: Because some browser does not support `white-space`

Comment: @user12345 Works for all the browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility. Chrome 1.0+,
Edge,
Firefox 1.0+,
Internet Explorer 5.5+,
Opera 4.0+,
Safari 1.0+

Comment: I am talking about mobile browsers.

Comment: @user12345 I'll check for that as well and I'll tell you in some time if there's any work-around.

Comment: @user12345 You are welcome. Please give me some time. `:)` I am checking them manually.